# NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, nonetype

Here is the code:

```
df = df.drop(
    ['PassengerId', 'Name', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Embarked'],
    axis = 'columns',
    inplace = True
)
df.head()
```

Its showing `NoneType` error both `drop` and `head`. Code looks right I think but I couldn't define the problem.

Comment: If you use `inplace=True` don't set `df.drop` to `df`. The documentation said about `inplace`: *If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return **None**.*

Answer (score 1):

`df.drop()` and similar methods do not return anything when `inplace=True` - they just modify the original object.

You will get your expected behavior if you remove the assignment, ie

```
df.drop(
    ['PassengerId', 'Name', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Embarked'],
    axis = 'columns',
    inplace = True
)
df.head()
```